# How to select rows from table using particular difference between two dates?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have table "user" in db with such columns: id, url, name, update_at(DateTime), updated_ext(DateTime), created_at(DateTime).

I need to select all rows, with particular conditions:

1. If in column **updated_at** the date has difference between today more than 1 day (the name of the variable is *on_start*)
2. If the difference between columns **updated_at** and **updated_ext** less than 48 hours (the name of the variable is *in_two_days*)

on_start = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)),

in_two_days = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2))

```
    q = session.query(user).filter(
        user.object_type == object_type,
        or_(
            user.updated_at <= on_start,
            ((user.updated_at - user.updated_external) < in_two_days)
        )
    )
```

When I try to run it, I got

> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You
> might need to add explicit type casts.

because I try to find the difference between two dates (updated_at and updated_ext and inside the format like this 'updated_at_1': (datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 8, 11, 5, 3, 620971),), 'param_1': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 7, 11, 5, 3, 620978)).

Is there another solution to compare two dates?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Bit confusing but I think I know what you mean. This should return an array of indexes where this condition is true

```
df = your_database
indx_array = where(np.logical_and(user.updated_at <= on_start, (user.updated_at - user.updated_external) < in_two_days))
```

Edit:
You could also use np.where() to return certain values where the condition is true and false. see https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.where.html